# IOS 9: Set camera orientation as Landscape or disable autorotation

Tags: ios, camera, orientation, uiimagepickercontroller

I need to set my camera orientation to landscape in iOS 9; my code works in iOS 7 and 8 but does not seem to work now.

In `iOS 8`, I call `CameraViewController : UIImagePickerController`, with setting `ShouldAutoRotate` >> return NO.

I have already tried this:

```
if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
{
    [[UIDevice currentDevice]setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight] forKey:@"orientation"];
}
else
{
    [[UIDevice currentDevice]setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft] forKey:@"orientation"];
}
```

There is no change in `UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight`, but if `UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft`, it's rotated 90 degrees but the size is not correct.

In the info.plist I have set it to only accept landscape orientation. What else should I do or might have missed?